# My vacation leave was not approved?

Tags: vacation

I apply for a vacation leave last month for the wedding of my sister. Submitted all the papers they asked including my plane ticket but i was informed that it was not approved. What should i do?

Comment: They said why? Your HR should have a guideline for those request.

Comment: Country, size of company, function in job, timing, roles, type of employment, arguments for not giving your holiday all would help in giving advice.

Comment: How did you submit your leave request? In person or using an automated process? Have you spoken to anyone about this (e.g. your manager or HR)?

Comment: Polish up your resume and start looking for other positions. Attend the wedding anyway.

Comment: Would they make you work through labor too?

Comment: Out of interest, why does your company want to see your plane ticket? And shouldn't you have got approval before you bought the plane ticket?

Comment: Why did you purchase the plane ticket before the leave was requested? Did it real take a month to get a response?

Comment: @DJClayworth In some places, you can claim tax exemption on the flight tickets. If the employer deducts taxes for the employee, they are usually required by law to verify the expenses before considering tax exemption. That is one possibility.

Comment: @MaskedMan There would still be no reason to see the tickets before approving the leave. None at all if the leave wasn't approved. Katie, where are you based?

Comment: Please do tell us were are you based, so I can avoid that country in the future

Comment: @Emory, that process would get you fired in any company I have ever worked for.

Comment: @HLGEM that would be a good thing

Comment: Companies need to know who is taking leave when so they can plan for the absence and make sure that not too many people are gone at the same time. It is childish behavior to think that others don't need to approve and be aware of such things.

Comment: @DJClayworth Of course, that is correct. However, it is possible that the "tool" which manages the leave requests asks for everything upfront, as against, "now your leave is approved, please upload tickets if you wish to claim exemption" (Logically, it *should* be done separately, but we know how tools are "interesting" in some ways). Anyway there is not much point in speculating over it, if OP comes back here, she can clarify why she shared the flight tickets with "them", though it probably makes little difference to what she should do next.

Answer (score 5):

> What should i do?

You should ask why it was not approved. Then your subsequent actions can be based on more than just a "no" decision.

If you think they don't understand how important the vacation is to you, you should explain it.

If you think they feel that they cannot get along without you, you can explain how they can.

If you think they are just being mean, you might be able to appeal to HR.

If you think they are doing something illegal, you should talk to your lawyer, or whatever is the equivalent of a Department of Labor or Attorney General for your locale.

If all else fails, you get to decide which is more important - this job or attending your sister's wedding.

Comment: If they still refuse to accept your vacation request, you always have the option of resigning

Comment: `If you think they feel that they cannot get along without you, you can explain how they can.` I would never do that, b/c obviously no one can get along without me.  But if they really feel they can not get along without me, then it is time for reconsideration of compensation.

Comment: @emory If you believe you have job security through indispensability, then a) you don't, and b) you're essentially _trapped in that job_.

Comment: @BryanH I do not believe I am indispensable.  I am not going to explain to my employer how I am dispensable.  I suspect they already know it.

Answer (score 1):

You submitted all papers they asked for *including your flight ticket* ? Your company seriously asked you to provide flight tickets to get a holiday approved and then rejects it?

Either someone in that company is seriously in the wrong place, or they want to get rid of you. I'd assume the first. In order of things to do: You go to your direct manager and ask him or her straight if he has told HR to reject your holiday or not. That's a very important piece of information.

The possibilities are: He or she isn't aware of anything and doesn't mind you taking the holiday at all. Or he or she thinks they would be better of with you there, but isn't aware that it's your sister's wedding and your flight tickets are paid and can live without you. Or they are fully aware and don't give a damn about what you want. These bosses exist.

If HR disapproved your holiday, you go to them next, armed with that information from your manager. What you ask them to do depends on what your manager said. If it's HR's fault, you tell them that your manager approves your holiday, and you want the person who decided tell you in person their reasons. Thoughtless, uncaring decisions are much harder to make face to face. If it was your bosses fault, you go to HR and ask for your holiday and a transfer to a different part of the company.

In the end, if the company refuses your holiday with no good reason, you can start looking for a new job. Signing for a new job means you can take your holiday, no matter what the company says. If you are confident you'll find a new job, but would like to keep your job, you can say "I don't know whether I will go on this holiday or not, don't be surprised if I'm not there on Monday". That puts the decision into their hand.

Comment: OP may not get any vacation. A trick more and more companies appear to be adopting is "unlimited vacation", which means they owe you *nothing* when you leave (in the US, any untaken vacation must be paid out). As for taking your vacation anyway, that could be grounds for immediate termination, at least in the US, in an "at will" state.

Comment: In some places, you can claim tax exemption on the flight tickets (and even hotel fees). The employer is required by law to verify  the expenses being claimed. I do not know if that is actually what happened here, but it is a possibility.

Comment: @BryanH, only some states require paying unused vacation not the entire US. I live in a state where it is not required and have worked in companies where the policy changed to not paying it out.